# Spring Integration unit test http:outbound-gateway

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-integration, outbound

Trying to figure out how to best unit test an `http:outbound-gateway` in a Spring Integration workflow.

Here's what our gateway looks like:

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway id="gateway"
                           request-channel="registrationQueue"
                           message-converters="jsonMessageConverter"
                           url-expression="@urlGenerator.resolve()"
                           http-method="POST"
                           expected-response-type="javax.ws.rs.core.Response"
                           reply-channel="nullChannel"
                           error-handler="httpResponseErrorHandler"/>
```

Specifically, we want to..

1. Assert serialization of the objects being sent; do the `message-converters` correctly process messages coming from the `request-channel`?
2. Verify response handling from the 3rd party service; what is the behavior given various responses (expected & unexpected) and errors (internal & external)?

We've got a number of unit tests that mock out the end points and assert the steps of our integration workflow behave as expected. Something like the following:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:test-config.xml"})
public class FileRegistrationWorkflowTest {

    ...

    @Autowired
    private MessageChannel fileFoundChannel;

    @Autowired
    private QueueChannel testRegistrationQueue;

    ...

    @Test
    public void shouldQueueRegistrationForFileWithEntityId() {
        // Given
        mockFileLookupService(FILE_ID, FILENAME_WITH_ENTITY_ID);
        // When
        fileFoundChannel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(FILE_ID).build());
        // Then
        Message<?> message = testRegistrationQueue.receive();
        assertThat(message, hasPayload(expected));
    }

}
```

This method of testing works great for the steps along the workflow. Our trouble is testing the the end point gateways..

- We can't mock the `http:outbound-gateway`, then we aren't testing it.
- We don't want to deploy a real HTTP service to interact with, that's more an integration test.
- The 3rd party service is only resolved by the `url-expression`, so there isn't a Spring bean to mock out.

Perhaps we can *intercept* the HTTP request Spring tries to send?

Answer (score 3):

In the [framework tests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-http/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/http/outbound/HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandlerTests.java#L98) we use a `DirectFieldAccessor` to replace the endpoint's `RestTemplate` with a mock (actually a stub). However, this doesn't test the converters.

You can get even more sophisticated, where the real `RestTemplate` can be tested; just get a reference to it (with the SI `TestUtils.getPropertyValue()` or a `DirectFieldAccessor`) and configure it as discussed in the [Spring Framework documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-client).

You can get a reference to the handler with bean name `endpointId.handler`.

Comment: Awesome, sounds like what I'm looking for, thanks Gary.